# Excel if statement with multiple and statements

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I Have a problem which looks very silly but I have been struggling for a while

```
=If(AND(A1="TRUE",B1="TRUE",C1="TRUE"),"TRUE","FALSE")
```

I am using the statement to determine whether my column D should be true or false.... But all the columns are returning false even the ones that are true, true and true.

Does it effect if the columns from A1,B1,C1 are coming from a formula itself ?

Comment: `=AND(A1,B1,C1)`.

Comment: Note that you have quotes around a (probably) boolean data type, effectively turning it into a string data type.

Answer (score 3):

Don't compare to the text `"TRUE"`.

Also, you don't need the `IF`; `AND` already returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Make sure that the formulas in A, B, and C return a boolean, `TRUE`, and not text,  `"TRUE"`.

```
=AND(A1,B1,C1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also just add them together:

```
=A1+B1+C1=3
```

or Multiply

```
=A1*B1*C1=1
```

Comment: Meh, had to be done.  It is also a nice lesson when trying to use AND in an array formula.